# Is there a way to show div inside a dynamic list item with jquery or js

Tags: jquery

Im retrieving products from the database dynamically into my page. However I want to hide product details and just show the product title then when a user clicks the title then the product details show. These details should only be for the particular clicked product title that has a unique generated id.

```
<ul class="products-list">
     <li class="cstm-list">
        <p id="cprd_622">Product A</p>
        <div class="prd-details" style="display: none;">
           <img src="/uploads/product/large/Alienware.jpeg">
           <p>description</p>
           <p>price</p>
        </div>
     </li>
     <li class="cstm-list">
        <p id="cprd_623">Product B</p>
        <div class="prd-details" style="display: none;">
           <img src="/uploads/product/large/Alienware.jpeg">
           <p>description</p>
           <p>price</p>
        </div>
     </li>
     <li class="cstm-list">
        <p id="cprd_624">Product C</p>
        <div class="prd-details" style="display: none;">
           <img src="/uploads/product/large/Alienware.jpeg">
           <p>description</p>
           <p>price</p>
        </div>
     </li>
```

```
<!-- Jquery -->
  <script type="text/javascript">               
        $(document).ready(function() {
             $(document).ready(function () {
               $(".products-list li p").click(function(e){
                  $('.prd-details').toggle();
                });
            });
        });

  </script>
```

Comment: as you provided no information about what is not working, i expect everythign to work

Comment: Oops. Whats not working is that when I click the product title all the other product details shows yet I just need one at a time on click

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to retrieve the prd-details relative to the clicked element like

```js
$('[id^="cprd_"]').on('click',function() {
       $('.prd-details').hide();
       $(this).next('.prd-details').toggle();//next selects the prd-details next to the clicked product name p tag
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="products-list">
     <li class="cstm-list">
        <p id="cprd_622">Product A</p>
        <div class="prd-details" style="display: none;">
           <img src="/uploads/product/large/Alienware.jpeg">
           <p>description</p>
           <p>price</p>
        </div>
     </li>
     <li class="cstm-list">
        <p id="cprd_623">Product B</p>
        <div class="prd-details" style="display: none;">
           <img src="/uploads/product/large/Alienware.jpeg">
           <p>description</p>
           <p>price</p>
        </div>
     </li>
     <li class="cstm-list">
        <p id="cprd_624">Product C</p>
        <div class="prd-details" style="display: none;">
           <img src="/uploads/product/large/Alienware.jpeg">
           <p>description</p>
           <p>price</p>
        </div>
     </li>
```

Comment: This works thanks. Is it also possible that when I click on a different product title the previous one will automatically hide?

Comment: yes, you will need to add `$('.prd-details').hide();` in the click function before the toggle

Answer (score 0):

Replace your 
`$('.prd-details').toggle();`
with the following...................................

`$(this).parent().find('.prd-details').toggle('fast',function(){});`

Or the Entire code is as follows...
I don't know the Principle of adding the Code snippet, the online snippet may work or not, but just make changes to your `JQuery` Code only. It will work.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">               
        $(document).ready(function() {
             $(document).ready(function () {
               $('.prd-details').hide();
               $(".products-list li p").click(function(e){
               $(this).parent().find('.prd-details').toggle('fast',function(){});
                });
            });
        });

  </script>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="products-list">
     <li class="cstm-list">
        <p id="cprd_622">Product A</p>
        <div class="prd-details" style="display: none;">
           <img src="/uploads/product/large/Alienware.jpeg">
           <p>description</p>
           <p>price</p>
        </div>
     </li>
     <li class="cstm-list">
        <p id="cprd_623">Product B</p>
        <div class="prd-details" style="display: none;">
           <img src="/uploads/product/large/Alienware.jpeg">
           <p>description</p>
           <p>price</p>
        </div>
     </li>
     <li class="cstm-list">
        <p id="cprd_624">Product C</p>
        <div class="prd-details" style="display: none;">
           <img src="/uploads/product/large/Alienware.jpeg">
           <p>description</p>
           <p>price</p>
        </div>
     </li>
     </ul
```

Comment: This works thanks a lot. Is it also possible that when I click on a different product title the previous one will automatically hide?

Comment: @FungayiMakoni yes, as mentioned by the madalinivascu. in above answer.

Answer (score 0):

CSS Code

```
.hide{
  display:none;
}
.show{
  display:block;
}
```

HTML Code

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="products-list">
     <li class="cstm-list">
        <p id="cprd_622" >Product A</p>
        <div class="prd-details hide" >
           <img src="/uploads/product/large/Alienware.jpeg">
           <p>description</p>
           <p>price</p>
        </div>
     </li>
     <li class="cstm-list">
        <p id="cprd_623">Product B</p>
        <div class="prd-details hide" >
           <img src="/uploads/product/large/Alienware.jpeg">
           <p>description</p>
           <p>price</p>
        </div>
     </li>
     <li class="cstm-list">
        <p id="cprd_624">Product C</p>
        <div class="prd-details hide" >
           <img src="/uploads/product/large/Alienware.jpeg">
           <p>description</p>
           <p>price</p>
        </div>
     </li>
</ul>
```

JQuery Code

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".products-list li p").click(function(){
   $(this).next('.prd-details').toggle("show");
  });

});
```